# In Multimap how to return value which has highest occurrence

Tags: java, collections, guava, multimap

I have a MultiMap from guava library

```
Multimap<Integer,String> maps = ArrayListMultimap.create();

      maps.put(1, "foo");
      maps.put(1, "bar");
      maps.put(1, "foo");
      maps.put(2, "Hello");
      maps.put(2, "foo");
      maps.put(2, "World");
      maps.put(2, "World");
```

In this for the key 1, I need to return value which has the highest occurrence. In the above case, it has to return map as

Expected Result:

```
[1,foo]
[2,World]
```

I tried

```
Stream result1 = maps.keySet().stream() 
                  .map(i -> 
                              maps.get(i).stream() 
                                  .collect(
                                          Collectors.groupingBy(v -> v, Collectors.counting())
                                          )
                                  );
```

Result:

```
{{bar=1, foo=2}=1, {Hello=1, foo=1, World=2}=1}
```

Comment: Doing it with a stream is just wrong. By definition stream should be stateless and operation on elemenets should be independent to each other. Here you want to count occurances and then perform some operations based on that in a single stream.

Comment: which Multimap are you using? I mean from which library

Comment: I have added tag guava. @Liquidpie

Comment: Just to clarify the question further, what would you expect the response to be when two values are of the same frequency (e.g. `foo=2` and `bar=2`)? Would you expect the output result to be `Map<Integer, String>` or `Map<Integer, List<String>>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not going to be very strait-forward. You first need to group by key, obviously. Then based on that `Key` you need to find the max occurrences of the corresponding `Value` (for `1 == foo`, for example). The only way to find that `max` is to traverse the `Collection<String>` that is mapped to a certain key. This complicates things even more since you use a `Multimap` and you could easily have things like:

```
    maps.put(1, "foo");
    maps.put(1, "bar");
    maps.put(1, "bar");
    maps.put(1, "foo");
```

As such, IMO, this could be written as:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> result =
        maps.keySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Function.identity(),
                x -> {
                    Map<String, Long> freqMap = maps.get(x)
                                                    .stream()
                                                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                                                        Function.identity(),
                                                        Collectors.counting())
                                                    );
                    long max = Collections.max(freqMap.values());
                    return freqMap.entrySet()
                                  .stream()
                                  .filter(y -> y.getValue() == max)
                                  .map(Entry::getKey)
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
                }
            ));
```

- I first group by `Key` (`1` and `2`)
- Then get the `Collection<String>` that is mapped to that Key
- Then compute a `Map<String, Long>` that represents the frequency of values. For example : `["foo" = 2]; ["bar" = 1]`
- I then look at the max number of occurrences. Since you are using a multimap, you could have a case when `["foo" = 2]; ["bar" = 2]`, for the same `Key`, so we need to take both `foo` and `bar` as the result.
- Based on that `max`, I find out the corresponding values.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be looking for could be achieved while iterating over the entries as :

```
Map<Integer, String> integerStringMap = maps.asMap()
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                e -> mostFrequentWord(e.getValue())));
```

The implementation of `mostFrequentWord` should return a `String` such as:

```
static String mostFrequentWord(Collection<String> values) {
    return values.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(v -> v, Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new UnsupportedOperationException(
                    "Empty collection as values in multimap"));
}
```

Comment: What is `mostFrequentWord` in here?

Comment: @Amongalen though I thought the naming would help, but yeah updated with the code as well.

Comment: add one more `maps.put(1, "bar");` to whatever the user already has...

Comment: @Eugene and either `foo` or `bar` (both eligible) turns out in the result...what your solution suggests further contradicts the expectation from the question and I quote *I need to return value which has the highest occurrence*... (value and not values).. to further `[1,foo] [2,World]` and not `[1,[foo]] [2,[World]]`

Comment: @Naman you are right, no question about it, I was thinking that the OP was not considering this case either, though it could be a possibility.

Comment: @Eugene sure, let the OP come back over that clarification. have posted a comment as well to the question for this test case. thanks for pitching in.

Answer (score 0):

```
maps.keySet().stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toMap(key -> key, key -> {
    Map<String, Long> valueByCount = maps.get(key).stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, Collectors.counting()));
    return valueByCount.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .orElse(null);
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do like below:

```
var valueFrequency = maps.entries().stream()
          .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting()));

var result = valueFrequency.entrySet()
                  .stream()
                  .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
                  .stream()
                  .flatMap(maxFreq -> valueFrequency.entrySet().stream()
                                          .filter(val -> val.getValue().equals(maxFreq.getValue()))
                                          .map(Map.Entry::getKey))
                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

Without streams, but using Guava stuff like [`Multiset`](https://guava.dev/releases/29.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) and [`Maps.transformValues`](https://guava.dev/releases/29.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#transformValues-java.util.Map-com.google.common.base.Function-):

```
@Test
public void shouldFindHightestOccurrencesInMultimapValues() {
    //given
    Multimap<Integer, String> maps = ArrayListMultimap.create();
    maps.put(1, "foo");
    maps.put(1, "bar");
    maps.put(1, "foo");
    maps.put(2, "Hello");
    maps.put(2, "foo");
    maps.put(2, "World");
    maps.put(2, "World");
    //when
    Map<Integer, String> result = ImmutableMap.copyOf(Maps.transformValues(maps.asMap(), this::findHighestOccurrence));
    //then
    assertThat(result).containsOnly(
            entry(1, "foo"),
            entry(2, "World"));
}

private String findHighestOccurrence(Collection<String> values) {
    return Multisets.copyHighestCountFirst(ImmutableMultiset.copyOf(values)).iterator().next();
}
```

If there was a MultisetMultimap subtype (i.e. `Map<K, Multiset<V>>`-like specialized `Multimap`, it would probably be the best structure to store your data in this case.